# `global` assertions?

Tags: validation, assert, verification, assertions

Are there any languages with possibility of declaring `global` assertions - that is assertion that should hold during the whole program execution. So that it would be possible to write something like:

```
global assert (-10 < speed < 10);
```

and this assertion will be checked every time `speed` changes state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any languages that *truly* do such a thing, and I would doubt that there exist any since it is something that is rather hard to implement and at the same time not something that a lot of people need.
It is often better to simply assert that the inputs are valid and modifications are only done when allowed and in a defined, sane way. This concludes the need of "global asserts".

You can get this effect "through the backdoor" in several ways, though none is truly elegant, and two are rather system-dependent:

- If your language allows operator overloading (such as e.g. C++), you can make a class that overloads any operator which modifies the value. It is considerable work, but on the other hand trivial, to do the assertions in there.
- On pretty much every system, you can change the protection of memory pages that belong to your process. You could put the variable (and any other variables that you want to assert) separately and set the page to readonly. This will cause a segmentation fault when the value is written to, which you can catch (and verify that the assertion is true). Windows even makes this explicitly available via "guard pages" (which are really only "readonly pages in disguise").
- Most modern processors support hardware breakpoints. Unless your program is to run on some very exotic platform, you can exploit these to have more fine-grained control in a similar way as by tampering with protections. See for example [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/hardwarebreakpoint.aspx) on another site, which describes how to do it under Windows on x86. This solution will require you to write a kind of "mini-debugger" and implies that you may possibly run into trouble when running your program under a real debugger.

Answer (score 1):

eiffel supports all different contracts: precondition, postcondition, invariant... you may want to use that. 
on the other hand, why do you have a global variable? why don't you create a class which modifies the speed. doing so, you can easily check your condition every time the value changes.